# Getting fields from quickfix message

Tags: python, quickfix, fix-protocol

I am using quickfix with python. Looking at the doc page [here](http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/python/receiving_messages_1.html) tells us how to get fields. Say a `message = fix.message` (with `quickfix as fix`) comes in from the counterparty. I can get the 35 (MsgType) field by calling

`message.getHeader().getField(fix.MsgType())`

which returns, for example, `35=X`.

My question is: is there any method which just returns `X`? Or do I have to slice everything (like `35=X[3:]`, which returns `X`) and know the length of all the strings therefore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is to get the field by first calling `message.getHeader().getField(fix.MsgType())`
then get the value by calling `fix.MsgType().getValue()`.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work . . . I ended up doing something like:

`message.getHeader().getField(fix.MsgType().getField())`

Answer (score 4):

I use a little util function

```
def get_field_value(self, fobj, msg):
    if msg.isSetField(fobj.getField()):
        msg.getField(fobj)
        return fobj.getValue()
    else:
        return None
```

that I call like this

```
clordid = get_field_value(fix.ClOrdID(), message)
```

for header fields, would look like this

```
def get_header_field_value(self, fobj, msg):
    if msg.getHeader().isSetField(fobj.getField()):
        msg.getHeader().getField(fobj)
        return fobj.getValue()
    else:
        return None
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you use the strongly typed approach, ie:

```
m.getHeader().getField(new MsgType());
```

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but what is `new MsgType()` ?

Comment: It's the "field name" for tag 35. See http://www.fixtradingcommunity.org/FIXimate/FIXimate3.0/en/FIX.5.0SP2/tag35.html so if you want any "field name" (which is basically a QF type) then go `new FieldName()` and QF should sort it out for you. For example: `m.getHeader().getField(new SenderCompID()).getValue();` or `m.get(new SettlDate());`

Comment: `m.getHeader().getField(new FieldName())` where `FieldName` is the field name you want the data for... You get qf types back so you can then go `getValue()` to get string values for most qf types.

Comment: I haven't tried this in PYTHON but presumably it's like QFJ

Comment: Ah, I see. Well this doesn't work in Python! If `new FieldName()` in Java initiates a new class, this is basically what `fix.FieldName()` is doing in Python. Which leads back to my original question

Comment: In Java the code `m.getHeader().getField(new MsgType());` returns X like you ask for...